# Visual Studio reports "the following specified text was not found" but only when doing a Replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I am tying to replace this:

```
:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:bvoid Page_Load\(\)\n:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b\{\n:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b
```

by this

```
:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:bvoid Page_Load\(\)\n:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b\{\n:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:bmyclass.dateclass.activite\(Request.ServerVariables\[\"LOGON_USER\"\].Split\('\\\\'\)\[1\], Request.Url.AbsoluteUri\);\n:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b:b
```

. I do find the first expression using FIND, but it says that it can't find it when I use REPLACE.

Here is a sample of my code

```
        //Affichage de la page 
    void Page_Load()
    {
        myclass.dateclass.activite(Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Split('\\')[1], Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        java.Text = "<script language=\"JavaScript1.2\" type=\"text/javascript\">var sess = \"" + Session["username"] + "\";var user = \"" + Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "\";</script>";
        Session.LCID = 3084; //Utilise des dates en format AAAA-MM-JJ
```

Comment: Obviously you've confirmed that the "Use Regular Expression" option is set in the replace dialog?

Comment: It could have been that, but I did check that box

Comment: Can you post a sample of the actual code you're which you're trying to run the regex against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape round brackets or quotes when using them in the replacement string, nor does it recognise certain character codes, including `:b`.

Firstly, change your find string to this (the curly braces around the outside are VS's own idiosyncratic way of defining a capture group):

```
{void Page_Load.+\n[^\{]+\{}
```

Then, change your replacement string to this (note the `\1` to refer to the capture group in the replacement).

```
\1\nmyclass.dateclass.activite(Request.ServerVariables\["LOGON_USER"\].Split('\\\\')\[1\], Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);\n
```

The "*the following specified text was not found*" error that Visual Studio gives you back is actually wrong - it's an issue with the replacement string rather than the string to find.

It's probably worth downloading something like this [Regex Search and Replace Addin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VS2008RegexAddIn.aspx) to save you the headache of having to deal with Visual Studio's bizarre regex syntax.